# Передать из скрипта текст в активное окно

Tags: bash

День добрый, подскажите можно ли передать из скрипта текст в активное окно программы на компьютере? Активное окно статично. Если да то подскажите каким образом.

Comment: можно, например, сэмулировав ввод с клавиатуры или мышки.

Comment: насколько я знаю баш не умеет работать с api окон понадобится программулина в любом случае которая и должна это сделать, принимать она будет параметры в баше а далее пересылать нужному окну. не помешает указать OS в вопросе, так как решение вряд ли будет кроссплатформенным

Comment: Эмуляция, то что нужно. Через утилиту xdotool передал текс. Спасибо!